# Getting 404 error for all images

Tags: support, android-app

Using Android SE app 1.0.57.

It seems that I can't open or see any photos attached to questions and answers. All I get is a 404 error saying that the file is not found.

[image]

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce...

Comment: @nicael I haven't tried with other WiFis yet but I don't think it's the WiFi problem (even when the WiFi may block imgur).

Comment: Do you see the images when viewing the same post in a browser, on the same device? If not then it's not the app fault, imgur is simply blocked on your end. Stack Exchange can't really do anything about it.

Comment: ..... the bug @nicael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, my WiFi blocked imgur, so that every link to imgur is broken. Problem fixed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251505/getting-404-error-for-all-images#comment821131_251505